# Android/Layout - Problems to understand why button isn't at the bottom of the page

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented a simple layout for a test program that i'm developing. The screen has only one image for logo, a textView with the title of the program and a button. I'm trying to use the linear layout because i want that each element goes in a new line. In my case, the image and the text could be really near, but i want that the button appear at the bottom of the page. I'm not understanding what i'm doing wrong. I have also added the android:layoutGravity property to the button with the "bottom" value but nothing changed. This is the code that i'm using:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="0sp"
tools:context=".DiLand"
android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/logo"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
         android:src="@drawable/logo2" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/titleApp"
        android:textColor="@color/titleColor"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="140sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:text="@string/startButton"
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:background="@drawable/start_button"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: why using scrollview?

Comment: There is the possibility that for old device with low definition the page become too big for stay in the entire screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Scrollview from it, it is creating problem, and replace below code its working, I have tested.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="0sp"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </View>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_width="140sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks it is working! I have only a question. What can i do with older devices with low screen resolution? There is the possibility that they don't see the button without scroll the view...

Comment: add ScrollView, but put the button outside it.

Comment: Don't worry it will manage by device itself. If answer was useful then right the answer and upvote please.

Comment: @pratik Thanks for the clarification. Last question. Why is necessary the View tag? In fact it is needed for which motivation?

Comment: When you declared LinearLayout, it will only allocate space as per your components are there. LinearLayout doesn't allocate more space. If you want to do so then you have to use Relative Layout.

Answer (score 1):

Change the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout, with:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

So the layout is still going on a new line with every View, and to the button add:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This way the button is going to be on the bottom of the screen/layout. Make sure, that the parent of the ScrollView is filling the whole screen.

Edit: 
Add to the imageView :

```
android:layout_above="@+id/title"
```

Add to the textView:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/start_button"
android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
```

Add to the button:
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"

Try it now and write.

Comment: i tried how you suggest but all elements are now overlapping. I don't understand if i have to add a view tag for divide each element...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `match_parent`/`fill_parent` height of `ScrollView`'s child is ignored. If it was respected, the `ScrollView` would be useless as the content and the scroll view window to it would be of the same height.

You can set `android:fillViewPort="true"` attribute on the `ScrollView` to make the `ScrollView` child expand to its parent height if it's smaller. This attribute has no effect if the child is taller than the `ScrollView` parent. This way you can have the button always at bottom while keeping it in the scrolling content.

Answer (score 0):

Its the LinearLayout so it will not allocate you all the sapce, it will allocate you in sequence only. try below code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="0sp"
tools:context=".DiLand"
android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/logo"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
         android:src="@drawable/logo2" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/titleApp"
        android:textColor="@color/titleColor"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        />

<View

android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
</View>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="140sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:text="@string/startButton"
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:background="@drawable/start_button"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: for be sure i tried also to paste it in my layout xml file but nothing has changed.

Comment: See I have posted another answer and its working, I have tested it.